# Reload Partial View using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My main view is loading a list from a partial view. I'm using Jquery to search over it, and that's ok. However, I'm having troubles in clear the search results: the partial view is not reloaded. I'm sure that controller is returning the correct results. What am I doing wrong?

Main View Code:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:right; padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;">
        <form method="get" action="@Url.Action("GetJobOffersList", "JobOffers")" data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#jobOffersPartialViewDiv">
            <input type="search" name="searchTerm" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "JobOffers")" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            <input type="submit" value="Clear" id="clearSearchButton"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="jobOffersPartialViewDiv">
    @Html.Partial("_JobOffersList")
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    autocomplete();
    search();
    clear();
});

function clear() {
    $("#clearSearchButton").click(function () {
        $("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").val("");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/JobOffers/GetJobOffersList',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").attr("data-otf-target").replaceWith(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the actual element and not the "attribute string". Change:

```
$("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").attr("data-otf-target").replaceWith(result);
```

to

```
$($("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").attr("data-otf-target")).replaceWith(result);
```

---

If you "expand" your initial code to multiple lines it would be the following:

```
var formElement = $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']"); // jQuery element of the from
var target = formElement.attr("data-otf-target");  // "#jobOffersPartialViewDiv"
target.replaceWith(result);                        // 'replaceWith' on string
```

and after the change:

```
var formElement = $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']"); // jQuery element of the from
var target = formElement.attr("data-otf-target");  // "#jobOffersPartialViewDiv"
var targetElement = $(target)                      // jQuery element of the target
target.replaceWith(result);                        // 'replaceWith' on target element
```

Comment: Thanks. But it stills not working after that changes.

Comment: @MissFilipa: Have you tried debugging it? May use the "long form" for this and tell us at which step it is "misbehaving"...

Comment: Finally, after a lot debugging, I figure out what was going on. Basically, when I was making the search the replaceWith was deleting my div containing the partial view, so when I tried to make clear the div didn't exist.